# Blazor TokenAcquisition is throwing Null Reference Exception

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, blazor

I have a Blazor server app that works fine locally but fails due to Null Reference exception when published to Azure.

The app uses Graph, and when I run it locally, it queries graph fine.  But when I run the published version, the ITokenAcquisition object (even though it claims to NOT be null) throws a Null Exception error.

I don't know if there are some "magical" link to values in the appsettings.json that works locally but doesn't work when published to Azure since the Azure configuration is handled different than running locally.

```
    public GraphHelper(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                              IOptions<WebOptions> webOptionValue)
    {
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        this.webOptions = webOptionValue.Value;
        GraphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { MentorConstants.ScopeUserRead });
        try
        {
            TokenInfo = (tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { MentorConstants.ScopeUserRead }).GetAwaiter().GetResult(), DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex, "Failed to get token info");
        }
    }
```

In the constructor, my tokenAcquisition object is NOT null, but when I make the call it fails.

Here's the exception details
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.CreateRedirectUri()
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.BuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync()
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetOrBuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync()
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String tenant)
at ...d.MoveNext() in C:\project\GraphHelper.cs:line 260

Comment: Without the code we cannot help you

Comment: as previous comment, difficult without the code. potential shot in dark - there was a bug identified recently. see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/releases/tag/0.2.1-preview  specficially bugfix #1

Comment: Thank you @AppPack updating Microsoft.Identity.Web from 0.1.4-preview to 0.2.1-preview fixed the issue.